# How can i get result in two data table after execute the Query?

Tags: c#, ado.net

After execution result is coming in two select statement. How can get in two different data table by c#?

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlConnString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "Exec SPSearchInvoiceList_rjt " + _customerID + "," + _ProjectInchargeID + "," + _projectID +
                            "," + _invoiceType + ",'" + _projectTypes + "'," + _invoiceAmount + ",'" + _invoiceCode +
                            "'," + _invoiceStatusID + ",'" + _invoiceDateFrom + "','" + _invoiceDateTo + "','" +
                            _invoiceRevisedDateFrom + "','" + _invoiceRevisedDateTo + "','" + _invoiceRaiseDateFrom +
                            "','" + _invoiceRaiseDateTo + "'," + Convert.ToInt32(PageIndex) + 1 + "," + pageSize;
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        var datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
```

I am trying to do it as above.I am unable to get records but i am able to get data once i execute commandtext in sql server. Please help.

Comment: loop through your datareader.... or issue more queries to get the results of the tables after

Comment: I tried the bellow code and get the answer.
cmd.Connection = con;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);
 
DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables[0]; // first select result
DataTable dt2 = ds.Tables[1]; // second select result